# use packageReleaseJar in depends on

Tags: android, gradle

I have a Gradle task that depends on other tasks. For instance:

```
//Dependent tasks will be executed first before executing requested task
makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar)
```

makeJar and clearJar are the task which I defined as follow:

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/outputs/myProject.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    def someString = 'build/intermediates/bundles/release/'
    from(someString)
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'myProject.jar')
}
```

I want to add another dependency to makeJar task. Gradle has a task called  `packageReleaseJar` which I want to use.

Following script fails:

```
makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar,packageReleaseJar)
```

Do you know how can I use `packageReleaseJar` using dependsOn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, ':ModuleName:packageReleaseJar')
```

We can also  add dependsOn when we define the task such as :

```
task makeJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: ':ModuleName:packageReleaseJar') {
   ...
}
```